# Side-scrolling background

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to replicate those old arcade games where the background continuously slides left (or up or down..) but I'm looking for some simple lines of code to achieve that goal.
Something that will shift the background image left and then reset adding another copy of the same image. Could you suggest me an easy way to add this feature to my code?

```
import pygame
import os

size = width, height = 750, 422
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
background_image = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()

pygame.display.set_caption("BallGame")

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image_rect.x
        self.image_rect.y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.image_rect.y < 321:
            self.facing = 'DOWN'
            self.image_rect.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and self.image_rect.y > 0:
            self.facing = 'UP'
            self.image_rect.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.image_rect.x < 649:
            self.facing = 'RIGHT'
            self.image_rect.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.image_rect.x > 0:
            self.facing = 'LEFT'
            self.image_rect.x -= dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.facing == "RIGHT":
            surface.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "DOWN":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_down.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        if self.facing == "UP":
            surface.blit(pygame.image.load("ball_up.png"),(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))
        elif self.facing == "LEFT":
            surface.blit(self.image,(self.image_rect.x,self.image_rect.y))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 422))

ball = Ball()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.music.load("bg_music.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

running = True
while running:
    esc_key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if esc_key[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    ball.handle_keys()

    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    ball.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

Note the comments for an explanation.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# this is the background image
# we need to blit it two times, let's call them "left" and "right"
back_image = pygame.image.load('background.png')

# this rect will store the position of the "left"-part of the background
back_rect = back_image.get_rect()

while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT):
        break

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        # your event handling here
        pass

    # this is the "left" image
    screen.blit(back_image, back_rect)
    # this is the "right" image, next to the left one
    # we calculate the "right" position by simply moving the rect by the width of the image
    screen.blit(back_image, back_rect.move(back_rect.width, 0))

    # we want a scrolling background, so we just move the position rect
    back_rect.move_ip(-2, 0)

    # it the right edge of the "left" image is zero, that means it's fully out of view
    if back_rect.right == 0:
        # so we reset the rect and start over
        back_rect.x = 0

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

and here's an example image (save it as `background.png`)

[image]

The end result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I have some problem with your solution. Yes, the background image slides left and i can se it's duplicate coming next, but after the second image the screen gets glithcy and i have this error: ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred.
Any suggestion on how to fix it? Should i make a loop to make the image continuously reset?

Comment: @Shuratt That ALSA error is not directly related to the pygame code, but a quick googling showed that it seems to happen a lot on Raspberry Pi. If you say the screen gets glitchy, maybe your screen is wider than your background image. In that case, either use a wider background image, or you have to draw the background image more than two times in a row.

Comment: I tried to use a larger background image and increasing the display value but the problem remains. I'm running Ubuntu in a VM.

Comment: @Shuratt That seems to be a completely different problem than your current question. Consider making a new questions with details explaining the problem, and tagging it with the Raspberry Pi tag. This will make it more likely to get an answer and also let people with the same problem to easily google for your question. If you do create a new question however, just make sure the same question hasn't already been asked.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman But i'm not using any Raspberry Pi, i am running ubuntu 18.04 on a VirtualBox VM on a MacBook Pro... could it be simply that i need to code differently from what i tried?

Comment: @Shuratt Oh, my bad. I don't know. The reason I suggested making a new question is that everyone that will be reading your comments here are people familiar with python or pygame (the tags you have in your question), and not necessarily Ubuntu, VirtualBox VM or about the error ALSA. Creating a new question with the appropriate tags and details describing the problem and a matching title might lure more people with the proper experience and knowledge and thus could answer your question more correctly. Also, people often search for such errors and an answer here in the comments is not searchable

Comment: @TedKleinBergmanThank you for the clarifications, and sorry, i'm new to this platform. Should i proceed to add more tags to this question or create a new one then?

Comment: @Shuratt Sorry, I didn't get your notification. I would suggest creating a new one since your first question and second question is fundamentally different. Changing the question would require you to edit both tags, the title and the body of the question, which is basically the same as creating a new one. And as you got an answer by sloth for your first question, changing your question would invalidate his/her answer.